# Produção vs Desenvolvimento - WEBPACK

Tags: node.js, vue.js, webpack

Gostaria de saber qual a diferença entre os modos de "development" e "production" dentro do Webpack4.

Answer (score 1):

O modo `development` é usada - como o nome sugere - por motivos de desenvolvimento. Você tem `source maps` do seu código e uma facilidade maior na hora de debugar, e também o seu código não é minificado, o que diminui o tempo de compilação

Já no `production`, por outro lado, é executada a nível de produção, o que significa que esse é o código final que vai pro servidor. Esse modo executa o `uglify`, que minifica seus arquivos de forma inteligente, pra que o browser possa ler de forma rápida e eficiente. 
E compila seus arquivos de origem em um ou vários arquivos minimizados. Também extrai CSS e imagens e, claro, quaisquer outras fontes que você está carregando com o Webpack.

O que separa especificamente a produção do desenvolvimento depende de suas preferências e requisitos, o que significa que depende muito do que você escreve na sua configuração do Webpack.